# RailsTutorial 3.2 Ch 9 - "before { valid_signin(user) }" causes RSpec test to fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, railstutorial.org

I'm currently in RailsTutorial 3.2, [Section 9.3.1 User Index](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users?version=3.2#sec%3auser_index).

Listing 9.27 directs an edit to the **`spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb`** code as follows:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do
    .
    .
    .
    describe "with valid information" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
      before { valid_signin(user) }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }

      it { should have_link('Users',    href: users_path) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',  href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings', href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }

      it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
      .
      .
      .
    end
  end
end
```

After doing this, the corresponding section of tests fails. I have been following the tutorial very faithfully, so my code and setup are otherwise pretty much identical.

After testing a few things out, I've found that changing the

```
before { valid_signin(user) }
```

line to read

```
before { sign_in user }
```

instead will make all the tests pass again. Is there something about the **`valid_signin(user)`** line that is off syntactically, or does this point to an error elsewhere in my code?

(The app works exactly like it's supposed to, it's just the test that says it doesn't.)

Comment: What errors do you get from rspec? What do your `sign_in(user)` and `valid_signin(user)` methods look like?

Comment: The RSpec errors say there is no method for `valid_signin(user)`, which is true - as far as I can tell, this is never defined in the tutorial. I was a little confused, but thought maybe it was built-in ... must be an omission then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at listing 8.34 you will see the def of valid_signin in the spec/support/utilities.rb file.

Comment: There it is! The tutorial said Section 8.3 (Cucumber testing) was optional so I skipped it - guess it's not so optional after all. For anyone else who runs into this, [here's the link to the section](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out?version=3.2#sec:cucumber).

Answer (score 0):

I am finding that much of the "optional" work is necessary for the ensuing code to work. FYI