# Michael Hartl's Rails 3 Tutorial: Section 3.2.2. Missing RSpec view/controller generation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm working through Michael Hartl's excellent Rails 3 Tutorial book, but I am stuck at section 3.2.2. in which he refers to rspec tests being auto-generated from

```
rails generate Pages home contact
rails generate rspec:install
```

I've noticed a few points in which the current releases of gems differ, and that's expected, but all I see in my *spec* directory is a file called '**spec_helper.rb**'. So I'm missing the following directories that, according to the tutorial, should exits:

spec/helpers
spec/views
spec/controllers

Is this something RSpec or Rails no longer generates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be using the 3.0 version of the tutorial - you'll be much happier if you use the [3.2 version](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages?version=3.2) instead. It's so new that it might actually still be in beta, but I'm almost done with it now and pretty much everything has worked exactly as listed, which is awesome.

(I also did the 3.0 version a month or so ago and had the same issues as you with things being out of date here and there. The testing suite in particular is majorly different between the two versions.)

Comment: Thanks. I found this just before I saw your answer. I'm kicking myself that A)I bought the book, and B)Amazon didn't warn me a little more strongly that a new version was coming out soon.

Comment: At least you can access the whole thing online, so no need to pay again. Just think of it as a contribution to Michael Hartl for his excellent work.

Comment: Very true. Thanks for pointing it out. Michael has created an excellent resource.

About the TDD intro, how did you work around that section, or did you just skip that part?

Comment: Which section do you mean? I started with Ch3 (the sample app), and I skipped the Cucumber testing in Section 8.3. I did run into a slight problem where there was a bit of code in 8.3 that I needed later, so if you skip that, see my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9382995/railstutorial-3-2-ch-9-before-valid-signinuser-causes-rspec-test-to-fa)